# Create s3 event to SQS using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I am trying to create S3 with an event that will fire when s3 receives the extension `.csv` and a specific SQS that will receive this information. However, every exemple I see online involves using Lambdas and I do not want this.

This is what I got so far:

```
service: test
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${env}
  region: us-east-1
resources:
  Resources:
    test-bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:provider.stage}-test
        AccessControl: Private
        NotificationConfiguration:
          QueueConfigurations:
            - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
              Filter:   
                S3Key: 
                  Rules: 
                    - Name: suffix
                      Value: .csv
              Queue: {"Ref": "${self:provider.stage}-testQueue"}

    test-sqs:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        ContentBasedDeduplication: false
        DelaySeconds: 0
        FifoQueue: true
        MaximumMessageSize: 262144
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
        QueueName: ${self:provider.stage}-testQueue
        ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 0
        RedrivePolicy: Json
        VisibilityTimeout: 5400

    dyanamoTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:provider.stage}-testeTable
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: complete_phone
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: complete_phone
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: The queue defined in the `NotificationConfiguration` of the S3 bucket is appended with `testeQueue`, while the QueueName itself is appended with `testQueue` - is that a typo in your code or just in the question posted?

Comment: just a typo, Will...

Comment: Did you get this working ?